# Ubuntu 18 Wifi Connected But no internet

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver, ubuntu-18.04

The WiFi is connected to the router, but there is no internet. The operating system is Ubuntu 18, and the computer is ThinkPad T460s.

I believe the issue is in the configuration in "/etc/network/interfaces". The file currently has only the Ethernet configuration, but when adding the WiFi configuration, it stops working.

Currently, I have this on the file

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet dhcp

# I tried adding the below configuration, but it didn't work
#auto wlp4s0
#iface wlp4s0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: Could you try connecting via ethernet connection to establish the issue is isolated to wifi configuration?

Comment: What's the output of running `iwconfig`?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "it stops working" when you add the wlp4s0 config lines?

Comment: Is dhcpd running? `pgrep dhcpd`?

Comment: After editing the configuration, did you try restarting the interface? `ifconfig wlp4s0 down; ifconfig wlp4s0 up`